How to filter only numeric part in of the query in linq
I have the following code in linq where I am trying to filter the numeric part from the column with the passed in number
public async Task<IEnumerable<Transaction_DTO>> GetTransactionDetailByNumber(string number)
{
    var query = from rm in model.table1
                join sy in model.table2 on rm.index equals sy.index into syJoin
                from sy in syJoin.DefaultIfEmpty()
                let underscoreIndex = SqlFunctions.CharIndex("_", rm.numerId.Trim())
                let numericPart = underscoreIndex > 0 ? rm.numerId.Trim().Substring(underscoreIndex.Value + 1) : rm.numerId.Trim()
                where SqlFunctions.IsNumeric(numericPart) == 1 && numericPart == number
                orderby rm.TransDate descending
                select new Transaction_DTO
                {
                    Col1 = rm.Col1,
                };

    return await query.ToListAsync();
}

I will have NULL, empty or alpha numeric data for numerId like 123 or C-1789 or NFP-9785 what I need is I would like to filter is only by numeric value of the actual column. My API will pass only 123 or 1789 or 9785. I need to compare and return the result. With the given code it is returning ant data

You didn't give any sample data so I am not sure about it: Why wouldn't you simply use yourNumberCol.EndsWith(searchNumber). (BTW, with proper relations, you don't need  to use join in Linq. It is rarely used)

I mean the data will have like C-1789 for numerId in my table

If you give that much information, then what I said is the simplest solution. (behind the scnes creating a "yourNumberCol LIKE '%searchNumber' " query.

"With the given code it is returning ant data" do you mean "not returning any data" or "returning all data"?

If you take out the where clause and return numericPart as a value does it have the proper data?

Can you not just do where EF.Functions.Like(rm.numerId, "%" + number + "%")

@Cetin Basoz yeah testing the scenarios

@Charlieface you would get some extra data using that (Like("%" + 2 + "%") would also match 123) but it might be easier to get some extra data and do a more precise filter in-memory.

@DStanley Well you could do where EF.Functions.Like(rm.numerId, "%[^0-9]" + number + "[^0-9]%") || EF.Functions.Like(rm.numerId, number + "[^0-9]%") || EF.Functions.Like(rm.numerId, "%[^0-9]" + number) or some other similar combination

If the value being searched is always of the form<alpha>-<number>, you can use the pattern "%-" + number or perhaps use rm.numerId.EndsWith("-" + number).

For the <alpha>-<number> case, you can use the pattern "%-" + number or perhaps use rm.numerId.EndsWith("-" + number). Or (||) that with a simple == check to handle the number-only case. (If neccessary substitute number.ToString().)  Will you ever need to match strings like "0123" or "ABC-0123" using the search value 123?

use regex : .Where(rm=> new Regex("^[0-9]+$").Match(rm.numerId).Success)
